# LsaEnumerateAccountsWithUserRight fails when connecting to Windows Server 2008 r2

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008-r2, lsa

I have some c# code that uses the "advapi32.dll" to connect to various servers to collect various information for documentation purposes.

Part of that documentation is getting user permissions from each machine.  I am using the LsaEnumerateAccountsWithUserRight function which seems to work on Windows 2003 machines, but not on 2008 machines.  I receive an 'access denied' error.  I have read a variety of threads on a variety of sites recommending disabling UAC (which I have tried) and using POLICY_VIEW_LOCAL_INFORMATION instead of POLICY_ALL_ACCESS when using LsaOpenPolicy (which I have tried) and none of it seems to work.  Has anyone run into this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I am able to use LsaLookupNames2 and LsaEnumerateAccountRights on Win2008 R2 (running VS in administrator mode).

```
LsaOpenPolicy(... Access.POLICY_LOOKUP_NAMES | Access.POLICY_VIEW_LOCAL_INFORMATION, out lsaHandle)
...
LsaLookupNames2(lsaHandle, 0, 1, names, ref tdom, ref tsids)
...
LsaEnumerateAccountRights(lsaHandle, sid, out hPrivileges, out privileges_count)
```

I used the following two references:

- http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/266094-lsa-functions - great start
- [I successfully called advapi32's LsaEnumerateAccountRights() from C#. Now how do I unmarshal the array of LSA_UNICODE_STRING it returns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112901/i-successfully-called-advapi32s-lsaenumerateaccountrights-from-c-now-how-do) - least privileges for LsaOpenPolicy, Marshal safely on x64 systems